# Slice Function with a MultiIndex Pandas Panel

Tags: python, pandas, panel, slice, multi-index

## Slice Function with a MultiIndex Pandas Panel

I created a `Panel` construct from `Pandas` with a `MultiIndex` (see code). Without `MultiIndex` I can slice the `Panel` to a `DataFrame` with easy commands:

```
PanelData.major_xs('A')
PanelData.minor_xs('zTwo')
```

If I slice the `MultiIndex` `Panel`, the result will be a `Panel`. What can I do to get a `DataFrame` back (Slice a 3D `Panel` => 2D `DataFrame`)? Why is the Result of a Slice with a 3D `Panel` a `Panel` too? If that is possible, the result should be a `DataFrame` from '2010-01-01' to '2010-01-03' with all zones ('zOne' - 'zFour').

```
import pandas as pd

ListLetter = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
ListCode = [2, 1, 1, 0]
ListZone = ['zOne', 'zTwo', 'zThree', 'zFour']
ListRegion = ['USA', 'CH', 'NZ', 'CH']
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([ListLetter, ListCode], names=['letter', 'code'])
columns =  pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([ListZone, ListRegion], names=['zone', 'region'])

PanelData = pd.Panel({'2010-01-01': pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)})
PanelData['2010-01-02'] = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
PanelData['2010-01-03'] = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
PanelData
```

PanelData:

```
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 3 (items) x 4 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 2010-01-01 to 2010-01-03
Major_axis axis: (A, 2) to (D, 0)
Minor_axis axis: (zOne, USA) to (zFour, CH)
```

NOTE: I'm using `Python v.2.7.6` and `IPython v.1.2.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, when you slice an axis of MultiIndex in a Pandas Panel, because the index is `MultiIndex`, after slicing the index is still there (in this case `Items axis: 2 to 2`), therefore the result is still a `Panel`

```
In [67]:

PanelData.swapaxes(0,1).xs('A', 0)
Out[67]:
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 1 (items) x 3 (major_axis) x 4 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 2 to 2
Major_axis axis: 2010-01-01 to 2010-01-03
Minor_axis axis: (zOne, USA) to (zFour, CH)
```

So if we use a slightly different method of `MultiIndex` slicing, the return is a `DataFrame`

```
In [68]:

print PanelData.swapaxes(0,1).loc[('A',2),]
zone       zOne zTwo zThree zFour
region      USA   CH     NZ    CH
2010-01-01  NaN  NaN    NaN   NaN
2010-01-02  NaN  NaN    NaN   NaN
2010-01-03  NaN  NaN    NaN   NaN

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast and qualified answer. I think it is what I was looking for.